# Move review indicators to the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar, sidebar

Ok, dare I say it... but I actually **preferred** the top-bar *without* the review indicators being there.

Now, I totally see the need for them to be prominent, but prominent enough for them to be in the uncluttered-"important-info-only"-top-bar™... mmmm. Not so sure.

---

How about we move these indicators into the sidebar? We then have the room to add *more* indicators for the *other* review queues (**ahem, bring some attention to the Close votes queue!**).

In my (unfashionable) eyes, something like below is what I was thinking:

> [image]

*Oh yes, I even had the balls to remove the "review" link from the top-bar, and instead link to it from the "Review Queues" heading; but this is optional.*

Comment: Okay, why was I actually shocked by the close-vote count in a mock-up for a moment .....

Comment: Side bar on all pages or just the home page?  I rarely have the home page open so I prefer the review on the top-bar.

Comment: @bluefeet: I'd say as many pages as possible? Home page, question page, tag pages... Is there any you've got in mind where they definately wouldn't fit?

Comment: @Matt I'm having a hard time seeing it in the side bar. For example, if I go to the [sql-server tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), I'm seeing  careers, related tags within sql-server, then my fav tags - I guess I don't see where this would fit in on the side. I think it would fall too far down on the side bar and I would be unhappy if this bumped my other items.  But maybe it's just me.  That's why I prefer it in the top-bar, easy access.

Comment: The real close vote count is almost as shocking

Answer (score 5):

Not a bad suggestion overall. I like the structure of it in the sidebar.

However, I do not think it would work out too well for situations other than the questions page. When viewing a question, it would be either above the related links (undesirable as it obscures highly valuable links), or below the related links which would push it far out of the way.

The indicators themselves don't really bother me, and it seemed that a lot of users liked them. Perhaps a change to the indication would be another way to approach this. Maybe the review text and background could change when reviews are present.